# Query run in Teradata Assistant vs Pyodbc returns different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, teradata, pyodbc

I am running this exact query (hard coded values and all) in both Teradata SQL Assistant and via pyodbc in Python 2.7. I receive different results from the two methods, and it appears the pyodbc one is incorrect.

```
SELECT serial_num, event_desc,event_level, count(*) as "Count", MAX(event_ts) as "Latest Event Timestamp"
    FROM mytable
    WHERE
    serial_num in('serial1','serial2')
    AND event_ts >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND event_ts <= '2014-03-31 23:59:59.999'
    and event_desc = 'My Test Event'
    group by serial_num, event_desc,event_level
    order by serial_num, "Latest Event Timestamp"
```

Teradata Assistant results look like this

```
serial_num  event_desc      event_level     Count   Latest Event Timestamp
serial1     My Test Event   1               5       3/4/2014 10:03:28.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               12      3/27/2014 13:01:25.000000
serial2     My Test Event   2               4       3/27/2014 13:32:59.000000
```

However, when run in Python using pyodbc, I get different results:

```
serial_num  event_desc      event_level     Count   Latest Event Timestamp
serial1     'My Test Event' '1'             2       datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 10, 5, 15
serial2     'My Test Event' '2'             1       datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 14, 2, 22, 47
serial2     'My Test Event' '1'             4       datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 22, 6, 36, 40
```

The differences are in the count and timestamp columns. I am not sure what, exactly, the query is doing in python. It returns valid time stamps, but they aren't the max time same for the `group by` and the count is incorrect. Why?

This is the ungroupped data:

```
serial_num  event_desc      event_level     Latest Event Timestamp
serial1     My Test Event   1               1/2/2014 07:11:22.000000
serial1     My Test Event   1               1/3/2014 10:05:15.000000
serial1     My Test Event   1               1/19/2014 13:32:17.000000
serial1     My Test Event   1               3/4/2014 09:16:15.000000
serial1     My Test Event   1               3/4/2014 10:03:28.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               1/19/2014 14:04:47.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               1/28/2014 13:27:00.000000
serial2     My Test Event   2               1/28/2014 13:57:12.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               2/5/2014 01:36:47.000000
serial2     My Test Event   2               2/5/2014 02:56:53.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               2/23/2014 01:57:19.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               2/27/2014 13:50:08.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               2/28/2014 13:55:51.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/9/2014 15:31:00.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/14/2014 01:31:36.000000
serial2     My Test Event   2               3/14/2014 02:22:47.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/16/2014 03:29:04.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/22/2014 02:07:04.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/22/2014 06:36:40.000000
serial2     My Test Event   1               3/27/2014 13:01:25.000000
serial2     My Test Event   2               3/27/2014 13:32:59.000000
```

The python code that is running is this

```
qry = <<Above SQL>>
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=server;UID=user;PWD=password;QUIETMODE=YES;', ANSI=True, autocommit=True)
teracurs=self.conn.cursor()
res = teracurs.execute(qry).fetchall()
```

Why do the `MAX()` and `count` statements work as expected if I run in Teradata SQL Assistant, but not if I run the query via pyodbc?

Comment: What is your session mode in Teradata SQL Assistant? I see in PyODBC you are using ANSI.

Comment: @RobPaller `SELECT transaction_mode FROM dbc.SessionInfoV WHERE SessionNo = SESSION;` returned `T`. I adjusted PyODBC to the same, still no change. However, I didn't think of looking at that. Thanks for that pointer.

Comment: You should write timestamps like **TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'**, but this should not cause an result like this. Can you check DBQL data to see what SQL is actually submitted to Teradata, maybe PyODBC modifies it?